# MySQL 5.1, Fulltext search does not find the word "more"

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a table with a fulltext on one column "volltext" type is mediumtext. The fulltext index is "volltext". I matched words on it like

```
SELECT * FROM `volltextsuche` WHERE MATCH(volltext) AGAINST('+search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

this will find any occurence correctly.

BUT never for more (no matter how often it is in the text).

```
SELECT * FROM `volltextsuche` WHERE MATCH(volltext) AGAINST('+more' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Text example: "more Gil Coste Corbo More
Fragile Ästhetik"

Wrapping the word with `` does not help.

```
SELECT * FROM `volltextsuche` WHERE MATCH(volltext) AGAINST('+`more`' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

What is this for a remarkable behaviour?

Comment: Does it match the word "Gil" in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

more is a stopword of fulltext search at mysql

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

Comment: Thanks, this make sense, I will see to delete the "more" word.